# Decrease stock quantity when a variation is sold using Woocommerce

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I am sure I must be something wrong or omitting the correct way to do it, but each time I sell a variation of my product, the stock decreases for that variation, but the total stock value for the mother product remains the same.
Is there any way I can decrease the global stock of the product each time a variation is sold?
Thanks in advance for any tip in the right direction

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a variable product, stock management works only for the variation, not for the main product. So you should disable 'Manage stock' in the 'Inventory' tab and use only the one IN the variation.

Comment: Thanks this worked for me. I was not able to find exactly what wrong I was doing.. Your answer worked like a charm.

Comment: Hi, although this works, My product is always in stock, even if variations quantity goes out of stock. What to do then?